# Windows 10: Having different files in different desktops

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I have recently installed windows 10 and tried the multiple desktops. It looks very good and useful. I couldn't figure out if having different files or shortcuts in a different desktops. Does anybody know if it is possible? if so, then how?

Comment: I believe it's only for different windows. The files displayed on your desktop actually come from the file system - a merge of %USERPROFILE%\Desktop and C:\Users\Public\Desktop - and there's no way to separate them for individual virtual desktops. Virtual Desktops for Windows have actually been around for a while (and have never offered this feature); Win10 is just the first time Microsoft built them into the OS.

Comment: Virtual Desktops are like tabs in a browser.  Every other tab still exists, and there is only one instance of the browser window itself, of course that is more to do with how applications are treated then shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is [Dexpot Virtual Desktops](https://dexpot.de) which is free for personal use.

Under "Switching Desktops", you need to enable "Customize desktop icons".

Note that this software's last release was [Dexpot 1.6.14 Build 2439 (2014-09-04)](https://www.dexpot.de/?id=changelog) and the last News posting on the site was:

> **February 15th 2016**
>
> Long time no hear! Thank you for sending in your feedback regarding compatibility issues with Windows 10 - we're aware of them. An update will follow.

[The last post on Twitter was 2017](https://twitter.com/dexpot) and on [Facebook in 2016](https://www.facebook.com/dexpot)

Proceed with care.